# Get and set HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im screen scraping some websites and sometimes a form is submitted or some javascript is triggered and results in HTTP requests for certain files. I can see the HTTP requests in my console. Is it possible to 'get' these 'paths/urls' and maybe append them to a div? Is it possible to change the 'paths/urls' right before the HTTP request is made? I'm looking for some 'general' way to do this without looking at codes of all these websites.

Comment: Explain yourself if downvoting

Comment: i didn't downvote, however i strongly feel that you should be a little more illustrious here, its hard to understand whats going on.

Comment: @Relfor It's very simple...Lets say you are on some website, you click on something and some dynamic content is loaded. If you open your console you will see the HTTP request being made to get this content. So my question; how can I get this information (the address as shown in console) in to my HTML project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like a browser extension?
For example, [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) for Firefox can be used to block every HTTP requests for viewing and modifying before they are sent.